# Unable to run ROS GUI tools after pulling a ROS image from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, ros

I made a ROS docker file from scratch , including all the required ros packages. After compiling and running the image and after entering the container bash, I was perfectly able to visualize the GUI tools like RVIZ , GAZEBO via local server. The issue arises when I pull the same docker image to another device and try to run any of the GUI tool, I receive the following error-

QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display rviz
Aborted

Also, when I type Gazebo, I receive the error:

rospack:Unable to find the package , though I have it installed.

I have ROS Kinetic inside the container

Comment: I guess the device you are referring does not have a display